# Sharing Redux state between two component without no parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react with redux and try to setup react component to two different DOM elements. I created two components to target the two different elements and want to share the same state between the component. After dispatch from the first component, the second component is not being re-rendered.

```js
export function eventRegisterDispatch(): redux.Dispatch<Array<EventRegisterModel>> {
    return _eventRegisterState.dispatch;
}

export function eventRegisterStore(): redux.Store<Array<EventRegisterModel>> {
    return _eventRegisterState;
}

var app = React.createElement(Provider, { store: appStore }, React.createElement(EventCourseContainer));
const eventMount = document.getElementById('multiple-location-app');
render(app, eventMount);

var buttonApp = React.createElement(Provider, { store: appStore }, React.createElement(RegisterButtonContainer));
const buttonAppMount = document.getElementById('multiple-location-button');
render(buttonApp, buttonAppMount);
```

Comment: you are creating elements, not components. You need to render them. However I would try to implement your logic in the react way – with parents, children and so on. As for now it is really hard to understand how all of this live inside your app

Comment: @VladislavSorokin I am trying to target two different elements in the DOM something like <div id="comp1"></div> something something <div id="comp2"></div<